# UIColor patternImage conflict with UIActivityViewController barTintColor

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uicolor, uiactivityviewcontroller

i am using the `UIColor(patternImage:)` to change the color of `UINavigationBar` just like that

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Bar")!)
```

but when i try to use the UIActivityViewController to share on Facebook or Twitter , i got that error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation`

is there any alternative approach to achieve this ?

*** Update ***

The only working solution for now is to change each UINavigationBar tint in all of the ViewControllers

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Bar")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try navigation appearance method.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navBg.png"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

Note: Image hight keep 64 pixel.hope this help.

Add key in info.plist View controller-based status bar appearance = NO

Comment: i already tried that before but this solution only affect the bar background and it makes the statusBar black

Comment: it's still not working , the statusBar looks completely separated from the navigation bar

Comment: I tested this work fine. you can try by creating new project.